# Using multiple methods with Blackjack

Tags: java, object-oriented, beginner, game, playing-cards

I am very new to Java and programming theory and am desperately trying to improve my knowledge. This is the first program I've made without help and really would appreciate some feedback. I know there must be 1,000,000 better ways to do what I did.

Notes:

- I want to move away from `main()` programming. How could I achieve this program using methods and OOP?
- I am aware that the `Ace` should not just be = 11 and should give the user the chance to dictate its value, but implementing that would not of taught me anything new.
- The way in which I calculated the dealers & users card value is atrocious, especially because I had to re-iterate it constantly. This is the biggest problem I want to fix.

Images of console to give you an idea of two runs:

[image]

[image]

Any and all comments are appreciated.  I really want to get to grips with basic Java programming concepts before my bad habits are too engraved to break!

```
import java.util.*;
public class BlackJack {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Scanner && User Variables
     */
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int usersDecision = 0;

    /*
     * Users && Dealers Value Variables
     */
    int usersValue = 0;
    int dealersValue = 0;

    /*
     * Suit && Rank Arrays
     */
    String[] card = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    /*
     * Array Lists Users Cards && Dealers Cards
     */
    ArrayList<String> usersCards = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dealersCards = new ArrayList<String>();


    /*
     * GENERATE DEALERS FIRST CARD
     */
    for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);

        dealersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
    }
    /*
     * Print Dealers First Card
     */
    System.out.println("The Dealer Was Dealt: " + dealersCards);


    /*
     * Deal Users Two Cards
     */
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {

        int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);

        usersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);

    }

    /*
     * Print Users Two Cards
     */
    System.out.println("The User Was Dealt: " + usersCards);

    /*
     * Check For BlackJack
     */
    if(usersCards.contains("Ace")) {
        if(usersCards.contains("King") || usersCards.contains("Queen") || usersCards.contains("Jack") || usersCards.contains("10")){
            System.out.println("You've Got BlackJack! Congratulations, You Win!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You Did Not Get BlackJack!\n[1] Twist\n[2] Stick");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You Did Not Get BlackJack! :( \n[1] Twist\n[2] Stick");
    }


    /*
     * Take Users Decision
     * Check Users Decision
     * While Loop
     * Switch Statement For Users Decision
     */

    int x = 0;  
    while(x==0) {

        usersDecision = kb.nextInt();

        switch (usersDecision) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You've Twisted - Your Cards: " + usersCards);
            System.out.println("You've Twisted - Additional Card Dealt");
            x = 0;

            /*
             * WHILE Twisting = True
             * Generate New Cards
             * Check Value of Cards
             * Bust/Twist/Stick For User
             */
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
                int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);

                usersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
            }

            System.out.println(usersCards + "\n");

            /*
             * Generate Users Card Value
             */
            usersValue = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < usersCards.size(); i++) {
                if(usersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
                    usersValue += 2;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
                    usersValue += 3;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
                    usersValue += 4;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
                    usersValue += 5;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
                    usersValue += 6;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
                    usersValue += 7;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
                    usersValue += 8;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
                    usersValue += 9;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
                    usersValue += 11;
                }
            }
            /*
             * Print Users Value
             */
            System.out.println("Users Cards Value: " + usersValue + "");

            if(usersValue != 21 && usersValue <=21){
                System.out.println("You Did Not Get BlackJack!\n[1] Twist\n[2] Stick");

            } else if (usersValue == 21) {
                System.out.println("You Got BlackJack! Congratulations!");
            } else if (usersValue > 21) {
                System.out.println("You've Bust! You Lose!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            break;

        case 2: 
            System.out.println("You've Stuck - Your Cards: " + usersCards +"\n");
            x = 1;
            /*
             * For Loop
             * Generate Users Card Value
             */
            usersValue = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i <usersCards.size(); i++) {
                if(usersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
                    usersValue += 2;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
                    usersValue += 3;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
                    usersValue += 4;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
                    usersValue += 5;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
                    usersValue += 6;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
                    usersValue += 7;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
                    usersValue += 8;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
                    usersValue += 9;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
                    usersValue += 10;
                } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
                    usersValue += 11;
                }
            }
            /*
             * Dealers Second Card 
             * &&
             * Check Dealers Value && Take Action
             */
            System.out.println("Dealing Dealers Second Card!");

            for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
                int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);

                dealersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
            }
            System.out.println(dealersCards + "\n");

            /*
             * For Loop
             * Generate Dealers Card Value
             */
            dealersValue = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < dealersCards.size(); i++) {
                if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
                    dealersValue += 2;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
                    dealersValue += 3;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
                    dealersValue += 4;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
                    dealersValue += 5;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
                    dealersValue += 6;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
                    dealersValue += 7;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
                    dealersValue += 8;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
                    dealersValue += 9;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
                    dealersValue += 10;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
                    dealersValue += 10;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
                    dealersValue += 10;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
                    dealersValue += 10;
                } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
                    dealersValue += 11;
                }
            }
            /*
             * Print Dealers Value
             */
            System.out.println("Dealers Cards Value: " + dealersValue + "");

            /*
             * Take Action On Dealers Value
             */
            int y = 0;
            while(y==0) {

                dealersValue = 0;   
                for(int i = 0; i < dealersCards.size(); i++) {
                    if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
                        dealersValue += 2;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
                        dealersValue += 3;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
                        dealersValue += 4;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
                        dealersValue += 5;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
                        dealersValue += 6;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
                        dealersValue += 7;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
                        dealersValue += 8;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
                        dealersValue += 9;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
                        dealersValue += 10;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
                        dealersValue += 10;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
                        dealersValue += 10;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
                        dealersValue += 10;
                    } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
                        dealersValue += 11;
                    }
                }
                /*
                 * If Dealers Value:
                 * <=16 == 17 < 17 == 21 > 21
                 * 
                 */
                if(dealersValue <= 16) {
                    int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);
                    dealersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
                    System.out.println("Dealer Has Less Than 17 - Taking Another Card\n");
                    System.out.println("Dealers Cards: " + dealersCards);
                    dealersValue = 0;

                    for(int i = 0; i < dealersCards.size(); i++) {
                        if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
                            dealersValue += 2;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
                            dealersValue += 3;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
                            dealersValue += 4;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
                            dealersValue += 5;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
                            dealersValue += 6;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
                            dealersValue += 7;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
                            dealersValue += 8;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
                            dealersValue += 9;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
                            dealersValue += 10;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
                            dealersValue += 10;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
                            dealersValue += 10;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
                            dealersValue += 10;
                        } else if(dealersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
                            dealersValue += 11;
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Dealers Cards Value: " + dealersValue + "\n");
                } 

                /*
                 * Checks dealersValue against usersValue
                 * Prints Response
                 */
                if(dealersValue == 17 ) {
                    System.out.println("Dealer Has 17 - Dealer Sticks\n");
                    y = 1;

                    if(usersValue < 17) {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Lost");
                    } else if(usersValue == dealersValue) {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Drew");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Won!");
                    }
                }

                if(dealersValue > 17 && dealersValue < 21) {
                    System.out.println("Dealer Has: " + dealersValue + " Dealer Sticks\n" );
                    y = 1;

                    if(usersValue < 18) {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Lost");
                    } else if(usersValue == dealersValue) {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Drew");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Won!");
                    }
                }

                if(dealersValue == 21) {
                    System.out.println("Dealer Has BlackJack\n");
                    y = 1;
                    if(usersValue == dealersValue) {
                        System.out.println("You Have: " + usersValue + " You Drew");
                    }
                }

                if(dealersValue > 21) {
                    System.out.println("Dealer Has Busted - You Win!");
                    y = 1;
                }

            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Not A Valid Selection");
        }

    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be repeating sections like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
    int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);

    dealersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
}
```

First, it does not make sense to use a `for` loop if the number of loops are just one. On the other hand, I also notice that you have

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    int randomGenNumber = (int) (Math.random()*13);
    usersCards.add(card[randomGenNumber]);
}
```

So why not refactor both into a separate method?

```
static final int MaxCard = 13;
void dealCards(ArrayList<String> cards, int num) {
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cards.add(card[(int) (Math.random()*MaxCard)]);
  }
}
```

And you can use it thus

```
dealCards(dealersCards, 1); // for the first type
dealCards(usersCards, 2); // for the second type
```

Also note that it is better to take out numbers such as `13` and declare them to be a constant with a good variable name that denotes their purpose. It helps you to understand your code at a later time.

--

```
usersValue = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < usersCards.size(); i++) {
    if(usersCards.get(i).equals("2")) {
        usersValue += 2;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("3")) {
        usersValue += 3;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("4")) {
        usersValue += 4;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("5")) {
        usersValue += 5;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("6")) {
        usersValue += 6;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("7")) {
        usersValue += 7;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("8")) {
        usersValue += 8;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("9")) {
        usersValue += 9;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("10")) {
        usersValue += 10;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Jack")) {
        usersValue += 10;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Queen")) {
        usersValue += 10;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("King")) {
        usersValue += 10;
    } else if(usersCards.get(i).equals("Ace")) {
        usersValue += 11;
    }
}
```

These sections seem to be repeating again and again. You could make them into a method like above, and call it instead of repeating them.

```
class NoParse extends Exception {}
...
String[] tenValcards = {"Jack", "Queen", "King"};
int parseCard(String card) throws NoParse {
   char c = card.charAt(0);
   int i = Character.digit(c,10);
   switch(i) {
      case -1: {
         for (String c : tenValueCards)
             if c.equals(card) return 10;
         break;
      }
      case 1: {
         i = Character.digit(card.charAt(1),10);
         if (i == 0) return 10;
         break;
      }
      case 0: break;
      default: return i;
   }
   // handle the parse error.
   throw new NoParse(card);
}
```

Using it,

```
usersValue += parseCard(usersCards.get(i));
```

Answer (score 6):

1. I'd use enums for the cards instead of Strings. It would make the code safer (since the compiler could check typos which is not possible with Strings). Related *Effective Java, 2nd Edition* chapters:

   - *Item 50: Avoid strings where other types are more appropriate*
   - *Item 30: Use enums instead of int constants*

   The enum values could contain the value of the card. It would improve [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and help you to get rid of the big if-else if structures, so it'd [replace conditional with polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). Reference:

   - *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*: *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism*
2. Furthermore, I'd create a `Hand` class to store the cards which a user or a dealer has, and it could have at least the following methods:

   - `void addCard(Card card)`
   - `hasBlackJack()`
   - `int getCardsValue()`

   *Code Complete 2nd Edition* has a good chapter about this (*Working Classes*).
3. The type of the `usersCards` reference could be simply `List<...>`:

   ```
   List<...> usersCards = new ArrayList<...>();
   ```

   Reference: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
4. `1` and `2` are magic numbers (in `[1] Twist\n[2] Stick` and in the switch-case). It should be a named constant. It would improve readability.